# How To Display Category list from Portfolio post type plugin?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, functions, theme-development

I'm new from WordPress development. I want to display portfolio category list in my theme, I'm useing portfolio post type plugin

[image]

what must I do ? what code or WordPress function must implement in my theme ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, the Portfolio Category in your website is called [Custom Taxonomy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies).

You will need a function called `get_terms()` which takes two params are the taxonomy you will get and an array. It will return an array of terms. Just surf the codex about that. After get the terms, you can use a `foreach` loop to display your result.

Example code:

```
$terms = get_terms( 'portfilio_category', array(
    'hide_empty' => false
));

foreach ($terms as $term) {
    echo $term->name;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it's work, now i want display the thumbnail image based on category, what must i do ? did i must use WP_Query() ?? or there is another way ???

Comment: Do that Portfolio plugin support category image out of the box? If it doesn't, for easier, you can use [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/) to get that function

Comment: I use something like this: $query_args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'portfolio_category'=>$t->slug );
    
$portfolio_query = new WP_Query( $query_args ); the_post_thumbnail( array(320, 340) );   and it works in my case. but i want to know, there is another way or not ( without using WP_Query() ) ? ?

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you meant. You're right. `the_post_thumbnail` will help you display the thumbnail image of a portfolio. For most case, you should use WP_Query for custom loop. It's the best way.

Comment: You're welcome. If you don't mind, you can mark this question answered to help other people.